# Why Terminated property of thread is set?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have multithread application.

```
procedure TGridUpdater.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  CodeSite.Send('Thread executed');
  sp := ConnectionFactory.GetConnection.LoadStoredProc('rab_itemData');
  sp.CreateParam('Tahun', ftInteger, sppdInput).Value := _form.tahun;
  sp.Open;
  Synchronize(DoProgress1);
  sp.DataSet.First;
  I := 0;
  CodeSite.Send('Terminated value is ' + BoolToStr(Terminated)); //The terminated property is 'True' here. Why?

  while (not Terminated) and (not sp.DataSet.Eof) do
  begin
    CodeSite.Send('Entering loop');
    Synchronize(DoProgress);
    I := I + 1;
    sp.DataSet.Next;
  end;
  Synchronize(DoProgress2);

end;
```

Method to run thread

```
procedure TFRABData.RefreshDataset;
var
  GridUpdater: TGridUpdater;
begin
  GridUpdater := TGridUpdater.Create(True);
  GridUpdater.OwnerForm := Self;
  GridUpdater.Start;
  CodeSite.Send('RefreshDataset executed');
  GridUpdater.Free;
end;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here? I don't see one.

Comment: My question is in comment on code..

Comment: Just be careful with progress updates. When you'll have one thread running and then `RefreshDataset` is called, you will start another one and terminate the currently running one, what may take some time. And, you'll be updating the same progress...

Comment: Yes, I just realize, to stop current thread, it must wait the stored proc to finish executing, and it still take some time and make UI freeze..

Comment: UI shouldn't freeze, UI thread is separated. And yes, thread is terminated when it finishes its `Execute` method execution. Then the only clean way how to finish it as soon as possible, is ask for `Terminated` flag as much as you can and exit when it's True, but you will still wait for the long running operations (if they're not cancellable of course). That's why I disclaimed my single thread idea.

Comment: I try @NGLN answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577021/how-to-free-a-thread-in-delphi) question. It call `Terminate` and then `WaitFor`, and that makes UI freeze

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are freeing your thread immediately after you start it. You have to let it live its own life. So to answer your question, it's the thread's destructor that sets the [`Terminated`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Terminated) flag to True.

```
procedure TFRABData.RefreshDataset;
var
  GridUpdater: TGridUpdater;
begin
  GridUpdater := TGridUpdater.Create(True);
  GridUpdater.OwnerForm := Self;
  GridUpdater.Start;
  CodeSite.Send('RefreshDataset executed');
  GridUpdater.Free; // <-- don't do this; let the thread live its own life
end;
```